# How to blacklist certain ciphers and key exchange algorithms in ssh and sshd

Tags: linux, ssh, security, cryptography

To get a list of all supported algorithms, I can run `ssh -Q kex`, which on my machine outputs

```
diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
diffie-hellman-group14-sha256
diffie-hellman-group16-sha512
diffie-hellman-group18-sha512
diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
ecdh-sha2-nistp256
ecdh-sha2-nistp384
ecdh-sha2-nistp521
curve25519-sha256
curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
sntrup4591761x25519-sha512@tinyssh.org
```

I also know I can add a line into my sshd_config and ssh_config files like `KexAlgorithms curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256` if I want to whitelist certain algorithms.

However, I don't think I will stay on top of keeping this list up to date. If my version of ssh is updated to include better ciphers, I want to be able to take advantage of those automatically (which is what would happen if I don't modify my configuration file). By trying to eliminate algorithms I do not want to use (for instance, `diffie-hellman-group1-sha1`), I have also locked myself in to not using anything better than the best currently supported algorithm.

Is there a way to configure ssh and sshd to say "Do not consider these algorithms" without also saying "And also don't consider anything except these other algorithms"?

I would accept answers specific to openssh and Linux, and you can assume I am using very new versions of relevant software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the man page for `ssh_config`:

> KexAlgorithms
> Specifies the available KEX (Key Exchange) algorithms.  Multiple
> algorithms must be comma-separated.  If the specified list begins
> with a '+' character, then the specified methods will be appended
> to the default set instead of replacing them.  If the specified
> list begins with a '-' character, then the specified methods
> (including wildcards) will be removed from the default set
> instead of replacing them.

Use the '-' option with all the ciphers you want to blacklist from the default list on the client.

Unfortunately, the man page for `sshd_config` doesn't seem to document the same option at the server end, but it does work.